# laravel 5.3 admin middleware using?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, middleware

I need some help about laravel 5.3 middleware. My problem is the following:

I make an app that has 2 front-end area which are web and admin.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;
class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return redirect('admin/');
    }
}
```

and I have 2 controls in App\Http\Controllers\Admin folder

> those are LoginController and HomeController

if I enter the localhost:8000/admin/ I go to LoginController and write hello. this is good but if i go localhost:8000/admin/home I see the other string write "home page" but i want to redirect to user admin/login if the user not authenticate but i could not do that.

I added middlewareGroup in Kernel.php

```
'admin' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

and added routeMiddleware like that

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

I want to tell it I don't want role system

I want to make 2 modules

1. user module ( it is in the web.php -> in route folder )
2. admin module ( it is in the admin.php -> in route folder )

user and admin different.

could user be an admin ? NO ... admin is different from user ... (other people)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this functions in your file App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapAdminRoutes();
    //
}

...

protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'admin',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/admin.php');
    });
}
```